# Java Read Textfile to get values in certain format

Tags: java, json, readfile

I need to read a textfile with the below data:

{“car”:{“name”:”Toyota”,”vin”:637834623,”location”:”SomePlace”}}

I need to get the name, vin and location

how do I go about doing this? 
I was thinking i could try read it using JSON, will it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example using [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) (google's json library):

Please note that you will have to use `""` quotes instead of `“”`, because the latter is not valid in JSON. You may use the `.replaceAll(...)` on the input string to replace these characters if you desire.

```java
public class ReadCarFile {

    public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Car.class, new CarTypeAdapter()).create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "{\"car\":{\"name\":\"Toyota\",\"vin\":637834623,\"location\":”SomePlace\"}}";

        Car result = gson.fromJson(input, Car.class);
    }

    static class CarTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Car> {

        @Override
        public Car deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject carObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("car").getAsJsonObject();

            Car car = new Car();
            car.name = carObject.get("name").getAsString();
            car.vin = carObject.get("vin").getAsInt();
            car.location = carObject.get("location").getAsString();
            return car;
        }
    }

    static class Car {

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;

        @SerializedName("vin")
        public int vin;

        @SerializedName("location")
        public String location;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers don't need to be quoted as you mentioned above, the below is valid JSON. Using a JSON linter like [here](https://jsonlint.com) will confirm that. Use a package like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to deserialise it to a Car POJO that your Java app can use easily. I personally like Jackson, although it can be a little heavyweight for simple uses.

```
{
    "car": {
        "name": "Toyota",
        "vin": 637834623,
        "location": "SomePlace"
    }
}
```

Comment: I should mention to get it to pass I had to change your quotes from  "smart quotes"  --> “ to a standard quote --> "